# converting a Tensorflow Dataset of time series elements to a Dataset of windowed sequences

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tf.data.Dataset(r1.4) whose elements represent a time series. For example (line breaks separate elements):
`1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9`

Now I want to run a window operation on it so that I get a Dataset of sub sequences of length WINDOW_SIZE for training an RNN.  For example, for WINDOW_SIZE=4:

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8
6 7 8 9
```

The closest Dataset op I could find is **tf.contrib.data.group_by_window**, but not sure how to apply it for this use case.
Another way is to use **tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder**, but it will divide the elements into buckets and won't have all the sub sequences.
A third option I thought of was to create WINDOW_SIZE iterators, and run them individually so that they point to consecutive elements, and then start using them in a sequence. However, this looks quite counter intuitive.

Comment: AFAIK, at the moment there is no way to do that within the `tf.data.*` framework. Assuming a "rolling_window_batch" operation existed, you'd find it in the `tf.contrib.data.*` module, since that would be a function that needs to be applied to the dataset via `dataset.apply()` (it can't be done via 'map' because it operates on multiple samples in the Dataset). You might ant to drop a feature request on the [TF's github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow), this would be a useful function to have ;)

Comment: Thanks, created feature request [#15044](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15044) for this.

Comment: I think the way to do it would be to create 4 datasets (each returns `1`, `2`, etc), consume 1 value from the 2nd dataset, 2 values from the 3rd and 3 values from the 4th so they're all offset correctly. Then you can consume one value from each and combine them. There's an example of using multiple datasets in https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets under the heading "Consuming values from an iterator", look at the 3rd code block there. I've never tried it though, so let us know if it works or not.

Comment: You'll need to keep a reference to each of the 4 dataset objects so you can consume the values to offset them properly early in the pipeline as part of your initialization.

Comment: @DavidParks did you mean iterators instead of datasets? I do think thats possible as mentioned in my question. But it'll get messy if we need a larger window size. Also, we'll lose other dataset functionalities like shuffle, batch etc. I think there could be a neater way to do this.

Comment: I think it's separate datasets that aggregate together, not just iterators. I admit that I haven't tried it, I'm going off what I understand from the documentation. I expect that you could parameterize a function that creates the appropriate datasets for whatever sequence length you're using this iteration (assuming you're not dynamically changing sequence length dynamically during training).

Comment: See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/16123, it will be shipped in 2018, TF 1.7+ (maybe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In TensorFlow 2.0, the `Dataset` class now has a `window()` method. You can use it like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.range(10))
dataset = dataset.window(5, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
for window in dataset:
    print([elem.numpy() for elem in window])
```

It will output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my self in a similar situation and I solved in that way (I wrote in the comments dataset values at each step in order to make it clear enough):

```
length = 12
components = np.array([[i] for i in range(length)], dtype=np.int64)
# components = np.arange(6 * 4, dtype=np.int64).reshape((-1, 4))
dataset = dataset_ops.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(components)
window_size = 4
# window consecutive elements with batch
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(window_size))

# [[0][1][2][3]]
# [[4][5][6][7]]
# [[8][9][10][11]]

# Skip first row and duplicate all rows, this allows the creation of overlapping window
dataset1 = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.group_by_window(lambda x: 0, lambda k, d: d.repeat(2), window_size=1)).skip(1)

# [[0][1][2][3]]
# [[4][5][6][7]]
# [[4][5][6][7]]
# [[8][9][10][11]]
# [[8][9][10][11]]

# Use batch to merge duplicate rows into a single row with both value from window(i) and window(i+1)
dataset1 = dataset1.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(2))

# [ [[0][1][2][3]] [[4][5][6][7]] ]
# [ [[4][5][6][7]] [[8][9][10][11]] ]

# filter with slice only useful values for overlapping windows
dataset1 = dataset1.map(lambda x: filter_overlapping_values(x, window_size))

# [[2][3][4][5]]
# [[6][7][8][9]]

# Now insert overlapping window into the dataset at the right position
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset, dataset1))

# x0: [[0][1][2][3]] x1: [[2][3][4][5]]
# x0: [[4][5][6][7]] x1: [[6][7][8][9]]

# Flat the dataset with original window and the dataset with overlapping window into a single dataset and flat it
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda x0, x1: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(x0).concatenate(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(x1)))

# [[0][1][2][3]]
# [[2][3][4][5]]
# [[4][5][6][7]]
# [[6][7][8][9]]
```

In the last step you need to merge the overlapping window with:

```
def filter_overlapping_values(x, window_size):
    s1 = tf.slice(x[0], [window_size//2, 0], [-1, -1])
    s2 = tf.slice(x[1], [0, 0], [window_size//2, -1])
    return tf.concat((s1, s2), axis=0)
```

This approach works just with even window_size